# (S)CSS of even components in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, components

I'm trying to make a timeline of some events in my life, I'm using a surounding `div` with a class `.timeline`. In this div there are multiple event `components`.

This looks like this
(To make it easier I've only taken the first 2 events. In reality there are close to 25 events like this)

```
<div *ngIf="showArray.length > 0" class="timeline">
    <app-timeline-item [shown]="showArray" time="8 januari 2001" name="Geboorte van mij" type="personal" description="Toen ben ik geboren"></app-timeline-item>
    <app-timeline-item [shown]="showArray" time="1 september 2012" name="Start in SVT" type="education" description="Start van middelbare school"></app-timeline-item>
</div>
```

With my current SCSS this looks like this
[Image of current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0KX3.png)

On this screen this needs to stay the same. At a larger screen I want to get the even div's at the left and the uneven divs at the right. At the moment I only get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0HG4.png) far. I'm not able to acces the CSS of the even/uneven components.

Below is the element result of my element inspector in chrome

```
<div _ngcontent-mef-c39="" class="timeline">
  <app-timeline-item _ngcontent-mef-c39="" time="8 januari 2001" name="Geboorte van mij" type="personal" description="Toen ben ik geboren" _nghost-mef-c38="" ng-reflect-time="8 januari 2001" ng-reflect-name="Geboorte van mij" ng-reflect-type="personal" ng-reflect-description="Toen ben ik geboren" ng-reflect-shown="work"><!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}--></app-timeline-item>
  <app-timeline-item _ngcontent-mef-c39="" time="1 september 2012" name="Start in SVT" type="education" description="Start van middelbare school" _nghost-mef-c38="" ng-reflect-time="1 september 2012" ng-reflect-name="Start in SVT" ng-reflect-type="education" ng-reflect-description="Start van middelbare school" ng-reflect-shown="work"><!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false" }--></app-timeline-item>
  <app-timeline-item _ngcontent-mef-c39="" time="1 september 2016" name="Overschakelen naar informaticabeheer" type="education" description="Overgeschakeld naar informaticabeheer aangezien dat dit dichter bij mijn interesse veld ligt." _nghost-mef-c38="" ng-reflect-time="1 september 2016" ng-reflect-name="Overschakelen naar informatica" ng-reflect-type="education" ng-reflect-description="Overgeschakeld naar informatic" ng-reflect-shown="work"><!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false" }--></app-timeline-item>
  <app-timeline-item _ngcontent-mef-c39="" time="31 juni 2019" name="Afgestudeerd aan SVT" type="education" description="Afgestudeerd met diploma informaticabeheer" _nghost-mef-c38="" ng-reflect-time="31 juni 2019" ng-reflect-name="Afgestudeerd aan SVT" ng-reflect-type="education" ng-reflect-description="Afgestudeerd met diploma infor" ng-reflect-shown="work"><!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false" }--></app-timeline-item>
</div>
```

I feel like I've tried everything
Can you guys please help?

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far? Do you mean that you're not able to set CSS rules to those components and are asking how to do that (my reply is posted for this scenario)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set global styles in your `styles.scss` file which is in the main directory. There you can select even or odd `app-timeline-item` elements in the `timeline` container. I would use the `:nth-child` selector. More information on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.php

```
.timeline app-timeline-item:nth-child(even) {
  // Your code for even elements
}

.timeline app-timeline-item:nth-child(odd) {
  // Your code for odd elements
}
```